# Visual Studio shows 'Configure settings to improve performance' notification for ReSharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.5.2 along with Resharper 2017.3.1. Every time I open VS, it throws notification

> Configure settings to improve performance.

I tried ignoring this message but it gets thrown every time I start a new instance.

When this didn't worked, I clicked on message and it took me to Resharper Performance Guide options. I tried changing settings for `Source Control plug-in in use.`. I changed its value to Ignore but the message still persists.

> 2 Questions
>    1. What is slowing in Resharper for which VS throws this error?
>    2. Why is this not ignored by VS even though I have asked to ignore this?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No answer in re-sharper knowledge base?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently setting all to 'ignore' is the answer.

https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000784870-How-do-I-turn-off-the-nagging-notifcation-Configure-settings-to-improve-performance

Comment: Amazing what looking on the softwares support board will find :)

Comment: That's not really an answer if you want some of those set to something else.

Comment: There's a bug associated with this with an apparent fix but not released at this time:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-467729